# Jenkins - getting "No type prefix:" when assigning roles

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to assign roles to users in Jenkins using the 'role based strategy' plugin. When I do that, I am getting a red text that says "No type prefix:" in front of every user that I am assigning a role to. Please advise how this can be removed.:
[image]

I am very new to Jenkins so any suggestions will be very helpful.

Regards
Ramesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to resolve we have to add twice.
In your example

Under Global roles

1. Enter only **jenkins** and click on Add and click on admin checkbox
2. Enter **USER:jenkins** and click on Add and click on admin checkbox
3. Apply
4. Save

Similarly for all other users which needs admin role can be mapped.
The same approach can be used under Item and Node roles if it is configured

By doing this we would still see > `No type prefix: jenkins` however role based permission would work in desired way.

If you are locked out then use following link to get access again-
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/access-control/disable/
and follow above steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally this issue has been resolved, even though there are duplicate entries for each user as pointed out. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: So now I have an entry that displays "No type prefix: jenkins" and an entry with "jenkins".  The one with the error message is needed to be able to login. The one without the error message is so that I know what user I have added.  This looks like a bug.

Comment: It is indeed a bug. The matrix-auth plugin got updated to 3.0, and the role-strategy plugin depends on it but didn't update to adapt so it's broken: https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/#releases see the 3.0 part

Answer (score 6):

use "USER:" for user and "GROUP:" for group .. eg "USER:ABC" ..this changed with the  recent plug in update ..

Comment: Thanks Dheer for the solution.
This fixed the cosmetic problem but brought in a real problem. Now any user I try to login with, be it admin or non-admin level, it keeps giving the message:
Access Denied
<username> is missing the Overall/Read permission


If I revert to the earlier form, then there is no Access Denied issue.
Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: @RameshMenon you got to give them overall Read Permission https://imgur.com/a/EybU1Ba

Answer (score 0):

Just update plugins:

- Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin
- Role-based Authorization Strategy